# BGE Python: No module name 'BGE'

Tags: python, game-engine

I can not get Python to work, I have followed YT videos and do exactly what they have done but I only get error message:

> No module name 'bge'

I have searched on Google, but I cannot find similar answers. What is wrong?

At the top of my script I do have `import bge`

Although, I read somewhere that the inport BGE has changed.

But I'd really like to get this to succeed.
I can get my game to work without python but I'd rather not and it would make it too complicated.

I'm using version 2.77.

Here is my blender file
 [image]

And this is the Script I trying

```
import bge


def main():

    cont = bge.logic.getCurrentController()
    own = cont.owner

    message = cont.actuators["message"]
    remove = cont.actuators["remove"]

    own.text = "I don't want to talk."

    if own["time"] > 0:
        own["time"] -= 1

    if own["time"] <= 0:
        cont.activate(message)
        cont.activate(remove)   

main()
```

Also this is the youtube clip I follow. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8klSGN1m5no&list=LLi0N8WDVMrYgCK_ni5ajv5g&index=5

Comment: another bug I have seen is in the text editor properties panel(ctrl+t) some times I get this error if "live edit" is checked as True.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got it working now.
apparently it was logic brick "scene" was wrong.
it was apparently have to be named "remove"
So it says in the script.
I had left the name "scene"
therefore error.

do not know what I'm doing now.
But I have myself solved my probelm.

But thanks anyway

(I will return soon .. have another problem, I need help I will never figure it out ...)

Answer (score 2):

BGE is lower case when used in python.

Try;

```
import bge
```

Also make sure you are running your script inside the game engine rather than with the 'run script' button. The 'run script' buttons is for addons. To run a script in the game engine you use the python controller logic brick.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. (And I write "bge" lowercase do not know why it is with big here ...)
But I manage to make it that I want to get python to do with logic brick.
So I intend to run on it.
But it is sad that I do not get Python to work.

Maybe there is something wrong.

Can I send over the python script I'm trying to get to work.
So anyone can check if there is something wrong.

Comment: See the second part of my answer.
But yes, attach the script to the first post so we can have a look at it.

Comment: Thanks again.
Yes i have done that.  I just press the run script to see if it works that way. but I think i understand I should not press the run script...
 I may have forgotten to select actor for my npc.
Therefore, the near sensor don´t work. therefore does not the script work.
I'll check it out.
But I'm at work now.
So have to wait until I get home ..

(I tried to get another near sensor to work but it would not move.
so I searched and then I saw that the "cube" must be an actor ...)